# Efficient way to perform many interpolations

Tags: matlab, loops, interpolation

I currently have 3 matrices: `X` (N x 1), `Y` (N x k) and `Xi` (N x (j + k)).

For simplicity in describing my problem, I'll assume `j=0`

Essentially what I want is an N x k matrix `A` where:

```
A(:,t) = interp1(X,Y(:,t),Xi(:,t))
```

In other words, the nth column of `A` corresponds to the interpolated values at the nth column of `Xi` based on `X` and `Y(:,n)`.

I am currently using loops to create the matrix `A`. The other option is to use the command:

```
interp1(X,Y,Xi)
```

The problem with this command is that MATLAB will create a `N x k x k` matrix because it interpolates across all columns in `Xi` for every column in `Y`. Thus, any speed benefit from avoiding loops is more than offset by the extra interpolations performed, especially if `k` is large.

Are there any third options that I am missing?

**EDIT**: I've been experimenting with using `bsxfun`, but I can't seem to get it to work right. I also wouldn't know how to adapt it with the problem with `j > 0` (see below).

**PS**: If `j > 0`, then the desired matrix is now

```
A(:, 1+tj:(t+1)j) = interp1(X, Y(:,t), Xi(:,tj:(t+1)j))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restate the question, we're trying to optimize/vectorize this code snippet:

```
X = rand(N,1);
Y = rand(N,k);  % Large k
Xi = rand(N,k*j);   
A = zeros(size(Xi));
for i = 1:k
  A(:,k) = interp1(X,Y(:,k),Xi(:,k));
end
```

The first thing to note is that vectorizing does not improve things.  For example, we can eliminate the for-loop with the following code:

```
tic
myColumn = mod(repmat(1:(k*j),N,1),k);   % The Y column for any given Xi column
A = arrayfun(@(a,b)interp1(X,Y(:,b),a), Xi, myColumn);
toc
```

And on my computer, the **vectorized version runs a factor of *N* slower**.  Why? `interp1()` does several checks on the input data X.  In the for-loop case, these checks happen once per column *k*; vectorized they happen *N x k* times:

- Is X sorted?
- Does X contain repeated values?
- Is X uniformly spaced?

The best way to optimize this code is if you know something special about the input data already.

- If `X` is uniformly spaced, you can calculate the bounds and linearly rescale `Xi` to compute your indicies. i.e. write your own `myInterp1()` function using `linspace()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, etc.
- If `X` is non-uniformly spaced, but sorted with no repeating values, you can use `interp1q()` to eliminate some of the checks on input data `X`. Note that this is *officially deprecated* by Mathworks, but still available as of r2012b.